# In uitableviewcell, How to include re-order view (MoveRowAtIndexPath) under custom view cell in iOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios13

we are facing an issue with UITableViewCell when using moveRowAtIndexPath in iOS 13.
we can't expand a custom view to trailing of the cell when we using moveRowAtIndexPath.and we can't give the same width as per the cell.

We want yellow view until the end of trailing in ios 13. refer screenshot, please.

> screenshot when running app in ios 12

[image: click to see screen here]

> screenshot when running app in ios 13

[image: click to see screen here]

Below is my code : -

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return headlines.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath)

        let headline = headlines[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = headline.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = headline.text
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
        return .none
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let movedObject = self.headlines[sourceIndexPath.row]
        headlines.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        headlines.insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
        debugPrint("\(sourceIndexPath.row) => \(destinationIndexPath.row)")
    }
}
```

Comment: what kinds of constraints have your yellow view in your tableViewCell?

Comment: Yes, we are using auto layout with 0 leading and 0 trailing .

Comment: Trailling 0 in reference to which view?

Comment: Trailing 0 with ContentView,                                                                                   it is working fine with ios 12 or lower version, it only giving issue with iOS 13. I don't think it's constraint issue. In Apple Documentation - "The UITableViewCell class no longer changes the backgroundColor or isOpaque properties of the contentView and any of its subviews when cells become highlighted or selected."

Comment: @ArvindPatel - Your code looks like you are using a default "subtitle" cell... How are you adding that yellow view to your cell? And how are you setting its constraints?

Comment: Hey, I'm using custom view in the storyboard